# Apontamento de diretórios em git

Tags: git, github

Estou começando agora a utilizar o serviço git, mais precisamente o GitHub, porém me surgiram algumas dúvidas:

Meus projetos em JavaScript estão todos em um diretório no meu Desktop, porém todos os tutoriais de git que li dizem para criar e configurar uma pasta local onde ficarão os arquivos que serão dados commit, eu criei uma pasta em meus documentos, mas toda vez que eu alterar os arquivos na minha pasta de projetos, devo copiar os arquivos pra pasta que criei para o git e através do GitBash subir os arquivos?

Isso ainda está um pouco confuso pra mim, afinal, agora devo centralizar todos meus códigos em todas linguagens nesse único diretório? Como funciona essa pasta git onde fica o tal do INDEX, etc?

Comment: Pense num repositório git como uma *pasta de trabalho "inteligente"*, que é capaz de acompanhar e versionar todas as alterações que você faz no seu projeto. Assim, para cada projeto você deve ter repositório separado, e o trabalho é feito dentro dele, não precisa ficar copiando de um lado pro outro. O github é basicamente um serviço online pra guardar e centralizar essa sua pasta.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo não é bem assim como você está pensando, primeiro você irá criar um repositório no GitHub e depois clonar em sua máquina. Após isso você irá copiar todos os seus arquivos que estavam em outro pasta para dentro da pasta do seu repositório, feito isso você não irá mais trabalhar na sua pasta antiga e sim dentro da pasta do repositório do GitHub aí todas as alterações que você fizer poderão ser comitadas e subidas para o GitHub por lá.

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho você criar uma pasta de trabalho para cada projeto. Após isso, utilize o seguinte comando na pasta escolhida. Esse comando inicializa um novo repositório local.

```
git init
```

Considerando que você já tenha um repositório local, execute o seguinte comando dentro de sua pasta de trabalho.

```
git remote add origin git://github.com/usuario/meurepositorio.git
```

O comando acima vincula um repositório remoto do GitHub ao seu local (pasta de trabalho).

Após realizar o commit, você pode subir as mudanças para seu repositório no GitHub utilizando o comando:

```
git push origin master
```